# Error while setting Visual Studio Team Services as deployment source for Azure Web App

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment, kudu

I am testing setting a Git repo in Visual Studio Team Services (previously VSO) as the deployment source for an Azure web app and running into an error.

I've encountered the error through both the Portal and Resource Explorer.  I have linked Team Services to Azure AD.

When I setup the deployment source I receive the following error.

> Repository 'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.OAuthException: Vso GetWebHookInfo: There is no registered handler in Team Foundation Server for the service hooks event type ms.vss-release.deployment-completed-event.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I've tested this against another VSO instance/Azure subscription in which I am the owner of VSO and didn't have any issues setting up the deployment source.  My best guess at the moment is that it is a VSO permission that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We investigated and it is an issue with VSTS. They expect to be releasing a patch sometime next week.

Comment: The patch is released, so you should no longer be seeing this. Can you verify? Thanks!